# Como inserir corretamente dados em uma fila em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, fila

Eu tenho que inserir alguns dados em uma fila, e eu tenho as seguintes funções :

> InserirPos - que irá inserir a posição do dado,
>
> RemoverPos - que irá remover a posição do dado,
>
> LerLista - que irá ler a lista que foi adicionada.

Meu código :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- <title>Web Page Design</title> -->
<script type = "text/javascript" />
function Lista(){

this.minhalista= new Array();
this.InserirPos= function(obj, pos){
pos--;
if(pos< this.minhalista.length) {
this.minhalista.splice(0,0,obj);
}
else{ 
alert("Posição invalida");
}
}

this.RemoverPos = function(pos){
if(pos<(this.minhalista.length+1)) {
this.minhalista.splice((pos-1),1);
}
}

this.LerLista = function(){
if(this.minhalista.length>0){
for(co=0;co< this.minhalista.length;co++)
document.write(this.minhalista[co]+"</br>");
}else{
alert("Não há objetos na Lista");
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Exemplo Lista</h1>
<script type ="text/javascript" />

var minhalista= new Lista();

minhafila.InserirPos(prompt ("Digite um texto : "));
minhafila.InserirPos(prompt ("Digite um texto : "));
minhafila.InserirPos(prompt ("Digite um texto : "));

minhalista.LerLista();
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

O problema é que ao colocar na parte do HTML para inserir as posições e dados, ele não acontece nada e eu não consigo solicitar ao usuário para inserir os números, e mesmo após isto, ele não aparece na tela os números.

Como eu posso arrumar isto, e solicitar e inserir de forma correta na fila os dados ?

Comment: Está a instanciar `minhalista` : `var minhalista= new Lista();` e depois usa como `minhafila`, e esse é um dos motivos pelo qual nem funciona, e falta uma `}` de fecho no fim para a `function Lista`. Mas o código que tem não joga com a lógica normal de uma Fila. Explique melhor o que cada método é suposto fazer.

Comment: O que é suposto `InserirPos` fazer? acrescentar o input à array?

Comment: já olhaste o debug do browser que estas a usar? vê se retorna algum erro